# C# Console program that contains a constant static field to display text in the output main method

Tags: c#

Using C# for a console program in MicroSoft Visual Studio 2010, I have made some changes to this with some help from you guys and this console program is running correctly; however I need to implement a constant static field that will display the motto "To Obey the Girl Scout Law" in the output section of the main method. I know it must be something simple so please bear with me. When I include the public static const string Motto = "To Obey the Girl Scout Law" in the bass class, I get an error message - The constant 'DemoScouts.GirlScout.Motto' can not be static. The following is the complete code for this project:

public class GirlScout
    {

```
    public static const string Motto = "To Obey the Girl Scout Law";  

    public static string scoutName;
    public static string enterName()
    {
        return scoutName;
    }

    public static int duesOwed;
    public static int enterAmount()
    {
        return duesOwed;
    }

    public static int troopNumber;
    public static int enterNumber()
    {
        return troopNumber;
    }
}

class MainClass : GirlScout
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Enter the Girl Scout's name: ");
        GirlScout.scoutName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.Write("Enter their Troop Number: ");
        string n = Console.ReadLine();
        GirlScout.troopNumber = Int32.Parse(n);
        GirlScout.enterNumber();
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.Write("Enter the amount they Owe in Dues: $");
        string d = Console.ReadLine();
        GirlScout.duesOwed = Int32.Parse(d);
        GirlScout.enterAmount();
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Seperate the input from the output:
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(GirlScout.Motto);
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Display the new information:
        Console.WriteLine("The name of the Girl Scout is: {0}", GirlScout.scoutName);
        Console.WriteLine("The troop Number of the Girl Scout is:   {0}", GirlScout.troopNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("The amount of Dues Owed by this Girl Scout is: {0}", GirlScout.duesOwed);

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you never initialized the value of scoutName, so what exactly do you expect to print?

I think you're missing a line of code like this:

```
GirlScout.scoutName = Console.ReadLine();
```

I have to say, though, that your class is designed very poorly. You have public data members, and your methods seem to have no purpose or meaning - you should brush up on encapsulation, and make your variables private. Use methods to change/get their values.

If you need any help ask in the comments or in another question.

Comment: Hey Daniel, how would I go about using a constant static field from which the motto "To Obey the Girl Scout Law" can be displayed in the output in the main method.

Comment: public static const string Motto = "To Obey..";

Console.WriteLine(GirlsScout.Motto);

Comment: I am getting errors that say: error#1 - Invalid token '('in class, struct, or interface member declaration error#2 - Invalid token ')'in class, struct, or interface member declaration error#3 - 'System.Console.WriteLine(string, params object[])' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type' and error #4 - 'DemoScouts.GirlScout.Motto' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: The above code is what I still have, only I'm not sure where your code that you just provided for me would be placed.

Comment: Oh.. The first line (The public static const string Motto = "..") goes inside your class, while the Console.WriteLine line goes in the Main method.

Comment: That's where I have everything but now I have one error message - The constant 'DemoScouts.GirlScout.Motto' can not be static. I have edited the original post to include the updated code.

Comment: My bad! I'm not completely used to c#, I come from another language - just remove the word "static" and it'll be fine. Const variables are apparently automatically static.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, everything is good once I removed the static. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It was my pleasure. In Stackoverflow, you should accept an answer or at least upvote all the answers that helped you. I'd recommend that you accept an answer (not necessarily mine) by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You aren't doing anything with the name that the user entered:

```
Console.Write("Enter the Girl Scout's name: ");
Console.ReadLine();
```

It should be this:

```
Console.Write("Enter the Girl Scout's name: ");
GirlScout.scoutName = Console.ReadLine();
```

You also need to change the type of `scoutName` to be a `string` rather than an `int`.

---

You should also redesign your class. Use instance properties rather than static fields.

```
public class GirlScout
{
    public string Motto { get; set; }
    public string ScoutName { get; set; }
    public int DuesOwed { get; set; }
    public int TroopNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Got another quick question, How can I get the motto "To obey the Girl Scout Law" as a constant static field and have it display automatically before the output in the main method?

Comment: I thought so too but this assignment asked for this? I just used a constant string to run it. Thanks for the input.

Comment: A const string is, by definition, static; it is not specific to instances of a class.  Eric Lippert discusses this in detail on his blog: [Consts are already static](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/10/don-t-repeat-yourself-consts-are-already-static.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You are not storing the name the user input, as you do with the other data.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see assignment to `GirlScout.scoutName`...

Side note: please consider not using static properties (unsless it is goal of assignment). Either create object with normal properties or not use them at all...

Comment: Good advice in your side note